# @Async with Spring 3.0.6

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-async

I am trying to implement an asynchronous call using the **@Async** annotation. Obviously since its a legacy project, the Spring version is 3.0.6 so it does not support the newer interfaces (**AsyncConfigurer**) and listeners introduced in later Spring versions.

At the moment the **@Async** call works just fine on a method which is needed to send emails. The calling code calls the method and returns to resume normal control. The **@Async** call then is invoked as a separate thread. All this is very good and serves the purpose.

The **@Async** call is on a method which is there to send emails in the application. However, sometimes there can be 1000's of emails triggered. This I assume would raise 1000 or so threads. Will this not lead to a problem in the application with so many live threads? Do these threads terminate on their own? What happens in the JVM in terms of memory usage and heap space?

Additionally I was trying to call this method from another method by marking that method as **@Async** but it looks like the thread is not created and the control actually waits there to finish all operations in that method. Why does it have a different behaviour? Not sure why that was happening.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How many threads it spawns and how things queue is up to how you define your taskExecutor bean.

Documentation here : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#scheduling

Comment: I have not used a task executor with it. I have not configured anything in the applicationContext.xml or any spring files.

Comment: Sometimes other parts of an application configure one and the Async annotations just pick these up. 

You might need to explicitly configure a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean and then assuming you're using XML in Spring 3 rather than programatically configuring, bind your Asynch support to that executor like this:

    `<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />`

Answer (score 1):

Your Emailtasks will be stored first in a (by default unlimited) queue.

> By default, the queue is unbounded, but this is rarely the desired configuration, because it can lead to OutOfMemoryErrors if enough tasks are added to that queue while all pool threads are busy.

If you are using just a Annotation, a default executor will be created by spring. This executor uses default settings, which you can change by configuring executor properties in you configuration file or configuration class:

```
<task:executor
        id="emailSenderExecutor"
        pool-size="5-25"
        queue-capacity="100"/>
```

and then in your code:

```
@Async(value = "emailSenderExecutor")
public void sendEmail(Email email) {
    [...]
}
```

Read more and how to configure executor: [docs.spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-namespace-executor)

Comment: i dont quite understand the bit of task:executor. I have only provided an annotation to a method which is called asynchronously. All leads to is a new thread which executes on its own independently letting the control resume from there on. I have not used any task executor

Answer (score 1):

**@Async:**
The @Async annotation can be provided on a method so that invocation of that method will occur asynchronously. In other words, the caller will return immediately upon invocation and the actual execution of the method will occur in a task that has been submitted to a Spring TaskExecutor.

> **How @Async Works:**

This behaviour of asynchronous processing is implemented using **proxies** for your class at runtime.
When a bean of your class is injected via Spring into some other class, Spring really injects the proxy instead. Therefore the relevant method of the proxy is called.

> Will this not lead to a problem in the application with so many live
>   threads

**Yes** it can you have to very specific in defining task executor configuration.
e.g. of how to configure task executor (in case you use spring xml configuration).

```
> <bean id="taskExecutor"
> class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
>     <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
>     <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
>     <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" /> </bean>
```

> Do these threads terminate on their own?

These thread are governed by the Spring Container.

> What happens in the JVM in terms of memory usage and heap space?

Obvious the more the number of proxies created the more heap memory is going to be consumed.

> Why does it have a different behavior?

I assume you created 2 async method in the same class and called one in another.
So when you are calling a method from inside the class, its a limitations of Spring AOP that the proxy never comes into play, but instead it is triggered as a regular method.